# Can I install OS from Virtualbox to disk?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, operating-systems

I have installed Linux distros many times by mounting ISO in Virtualbox and installing it from virtual machine to disk. It always seemed to work, although is it safe and should everything work fine?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you mean installing to a physical disk or to a virtual disk in your virtual machine? Are you mounting a physical disk inside your virtual machine?

Comment: I mean installing to a physical disk, so I can mount it later e.g. in my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly safe.  If the .iso is good, then the install is fine.